# multiple images input for a CNN model

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, unet-neural-network

I'm trying to conceive a CNN model that takes for input 3 images of the same dimensions showing different characteristics of the same body part and outputs one image.

What's the best way to input these images in the model? Should I merge them into one image and put them side by side for example for each sample? If so, what's the equivalent in terms of matrices operations to do so?